# Hide URL for server side redirect

Tags: http-redirect

**Configuration:** Server is iplanet 6.1, client side browser is ie6

I have a url: `http://example.com/signOnTodef?cmd=login`

This request is basically received by the iplanet 6.1. Here I have a plugin which does some cookie authentications and redirects it to another server:

```
http://example.net?theQueryStringFromBeforeABitModified
```

So this is a server side redirect (302).

Now my problem is that this url `http://def.com?theQueryStringFromBeforeABitModified` shows up on the browser. I don't want this to happen. What can I do to stop the same?

Comment: Check if your server supports [Reverse Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) -- this will allow you to serve content from another server trough your server without changing URL in browser.

Comment: no it doesnot have a reverse proxy. is there no other way.. is there a way from the user side(i mean the browser side)? Actually it is not purely putting up the url on the address bar. But the original website will have a button which when clicked sends the request to server abc.com

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 302 is not a "Server Side" redirect. It is just a redirect. You can't do a server side redirect, because it's the client you want to see the page, not your server.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing something like this equivalent in PHP. I don't know what an iplanet server is or if it has PHP installed even, but:

```
<?php

    $file = file_get_contents('http://def.com'.$queryString);
    echo str_ireplace('<head>', '<head>'."\n\t".'<base href="http://def.com/" />', $file);

?>
```

Or something like that might work depending on the file you are trying to display to the user.
Keep in mind there is no redirect happening here. Your server will be downloading http://def.com for every request and then outputting it to the user.